ZIO#memoize inside a service
I am designing a ZIO service. And I have to use memoization in it's internal logic. How can I do that?
For example, if a method (or all the methods) of a service require some kind of authorization with a remote host, how can I make sure the authorization procedure is performed only once?
trait ServiceA {
  def doSomething(question: String): Task[String]
}

class RemoteServiceA(username: String, password: String, httpClient: HttpClient) extends ServiceA {

  private val authorize: Task[Cookie] = for {
    req <- ZIO.attempt {
      HttpRequestBuilder()
        .setUri("https://.../auth/")
        .setUsername(username)
        .setPassword(password)
        .build()
    }
    resp <- httpClient.sendRequest(req)
  } yield resp.getCookie

  override def doSomething(question: String): Task[String] = for {
    authCookie <- authorize
    req = HttpRequestBuilder().setUri(s"https://.../do-something?q=$question")
    answer <- httpClient.sendRequest(req)
  } yield answer

}


Now as far as I understand, I cannot simply use authorize.memoize here, it won't work like that. And I have to move authorization routine outside of the RemoteServiceA class, and pass a memoizedAuth: Task[Cookie] as a constructor parameter. But in my opinion this ruins the code encapsulation principle, as the authorization process is the internal logic of the service itself. Things become more ugly in case when I have multiple private methods returning values which I want to (lazily) calculate once and memoize for (potential) future use. The constructor gets bloated with memoizedSomething: Task[Something] and memoizedSomethingElse: Task[SomethingElse], and a lot of internal class logic must be moved outside the class to someplace else.
Is there a better approach for such a scenario?

Wouldn't a "regular" cache be easier to manage?

Why won't authorize.memoize work? I am probably missing something but it seems to me that it should ...

ZIO#memoize has return type of UIO[ZIO[R, E, A]]. You cannot just flatten it, because it is not supposed to work this way. Each time you are mapping or flatMapping the outer UIO, the memoization just starts over. So having UIO[ZIO[R, E, Cookie]] inside my service I cannot get the cookie multiple times without starting the authorization process again and again.
